# Unable to set property on model

Tags: php, laravel

When creating a related message I've noticed the `message` column is not being set but remains set to `null`.

```
    $message = $lastSeason->messages()->make([
        'type' => \App\Message::SEASON,
        'message' => ['this should be converted to json on save'],
    ]);
    dd($message->toArray());
```

The above outputs:

```
array:3 [
  "type" => "season"
  "message" => null
  "season_id" => 1
]
```

Here's both the `Season` and `Message` models:

```
class Message extends Model
{
    const SEASON = 'season';

    protected $guarded = [
        'id',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'message' => 'array',
    ];

    public function season() : BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Season::class);
    }
}


class Season extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [
        'id',
    ];

    public function messages() : HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
    }
}
```

This isn't a guarded attribute, so is there something else I'm overlooking on these models?

Answer (score 2):

Try to save encoded data

```
$message = $lastSeason->messages()->make([
        'type' => \App\Message::SEASON,
        'message' => json_encode('this should be converted to json on save'),
]);
```

Dont forget enable 
`$fillable = ['message','type']` on Message model

And your your database should have a JSON or TEXT field type that contains serialized JSON.

Regarding by [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)

Comment: According to the docs, `fillable` doesn't need to be defined when `guarded` is.  Since `message` isn't guarded, fillable is assumed.  Encoding the field and removing `$casts` does not resolve the issue.

Comment: does 'message' has JSON or TEXT field type?

Comment: `message` is a `json` field

Comment: @Webnet maybe I should recreate your problem if your problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you got `make()` from or why there is no exception thrown. In the [Laravel API docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.html), there is no such method defined. I think you are looking for `create()` as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships).

```
$message = $lastSeason->messages()->create([
    'type' => \App\Message::SEASON,
    'message' => ['this should be converted to json on save'],
]);
```

Optionally, if `make()` method actually exists, you can try running `->save()` method on top of it.

Comment: It doesn't https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.html

Comment: class HasMany extends HasOneOrMany{} and Webnet showed the output for us in question

Comment: Didn't dig that deep, anyway, the description says: `Create and return an un-saved instance of the related model.` So the optional part of my answer still stands, he need to call `save()`

Comment: @veNuker In my post I showed that `make()` successfully creates the object, but it's `message` property is not populated.  This is consistent with what happens when I use `create` except `create` throws an error because `message` can't be `null`.